# extras.getLong() seems to return 0 no matter what the key string is

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

In an application I'm currently working on I have my first activity with a ListView which is populated from an ArrayList saved to the apps internal memory. Either by using the menu button to select 'Add' or by tapping an existing item in the menu I can get to my second activity which is an edit page.

In the first activity if the Add button is pressed, there are no extras passed in the intent and no fields (text boxes, etc) need to be filled in the edit activity. If an existing item is clicked in the first activity, this passes the row ID of that item as an extra in the Intent, with the key string as "_id".

I understand that *Bundle.getLong("_id");* should return null if no extra has been passed with the intent. My problem is that for some reason, getLong() is always returning 0. I tried putting some gibberish as the key string for getLong() but it still returns 0. Has anyone come across this problem before?

I would also like to add that I have two other sets of activities similar to this, using the same method to get the rowId if it has been passed, and they all work fine.

I haven't been able to find any common problems that might cause this. Thanks in advance for any help.

[EDIT]

Apologies for any confusing and not showing this code previously. As a few people have commented getLong will return 0 if it cant find anything, however the code I use sets mRowId to null if this is the case, or at least I assume it does. This bit kinda confused my but it seemed to work when no other extra was passed with the intent.

```
mRowId = extras != null
? extras.getLong("_id")
: null;
```

I also had another mess around and found that if any extra value is passed with the intent (regardless of its key) it will cause it to return 0 rather than null. I assume this code doesn't work if another extra is passed. If that is the case is there a better way to pass the rowId if necessary and set it as null if nothing is passed.

Comment: You should post code for the `Intent` creation and you activity's `onCreate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the docs say that if the mapping is not found "0L" is returned.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getLong(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29)

(also the type "long" is a primitive and cannot be null).

You could use this:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getLong(java.lang.String,%20long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getLong%28java.lang.String,%20long%29)

in which you can define a default value to receive when the key is not found (e.g. -1).

Comment: Its actually using the type Long, being an object that wraps the primitive long.

Comment: Where have you seen that? The method signature for getLong() indicates it returns a 'long' type, not 'Long'. However I didn't look in the Android source code, so maybe behind the scenes it actually uses a Long. Anyway, the fact that it returns 0 and not null is what is being said in the docs.

Comment: I read this method in a few books which were referring to populating fields after selecting an item from a listview. It honestly does work, in the other answer I just explained why I think its doing it. It seems that if any extra is passed with the intent, it does return 0 rather than null. As soon as I removed the putExtra() it returned null as expected. Just need to figure out how to pass the two parameters that I need.

Comment: but it doesn't make sense. The primitive long cannot be null..so how can getLong() return null for you? I think you should post your code for the Activity creation, Intent setting, etc. so we can understand better :)

Comment: Apologies I editted the main post, as I mentioned in there I didn't quite realise what this bit did, now that you have explained that getLong can never return null it makes sense that this piece of code is solving it.

Comment: @WilliamStewart It will never work the way you are trying to do it. Read my post for more clarification. The reason you are getting null with no putExtra() methods passed with your intent is because your Bundle is null.

Comment: Ahhh I see, now it makes sense. So when any extra is passed, it will perform getLong and return 0, otherwise if nothing is passed it will just return null. It works fine with my other activities that only ever pass 1 extra, or none. This is basically a list of Rules for a specific state, so the rule edit page requires a row id if a specific rule item is clicked, and the state id of the specific state. I guess I'll check out the default value method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, using the getLong method with the default value worked.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that it is supposed to return 0 if no mapping is found. The function getLong() returns a long primitive, which can never be null. If you are mapping it to a Long object, it will still have a zero value, because you are just passing it a 0 value. Java is smart enough to assign primitive values to the corresponding box object. For example:

```
//This is valid Java code
int a = 5;
Integer b = a;
```

You have 2 solutions:

1) If you absolutely need to have a null value, you can extend your own Long wrapper class which extends the Parcelable interface. Then when you can call Bundle.getParcelable("key") you will get a null value if the key doesn't exist.

2) Use the function getLong (String key, long defaultValue). Set the default value to some constant number that will never be used in your app. Then if the function returns this value you know the key doesn't exist. This is only possible if you can guarantee a long value that will never be valid data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, using the getLong method with the default value worked.

Answer (score 0):

the bundle is not the same as the intent. you have to use getIntent().getExtras().getLong(). (assuming you got mixed up and are using the savedinstance)

Comment: Whoops, didn't read the last part of your post corrently. Put logs to make sure you are setting it correctly, and it could also be a problem depening on whether or not the activity already exists in the backstack - it could be using an old intent maybe?

Comment: It seems that when any extra is passed with the intent, no matter what the the key string is, it causes getLong to return 0 rather than null. I was passing a different extra with the intent, called "_stateId". I assumed it being different to the "_id" string I was searching for would mean it would return null. However I just removed that other putExtra line and it works fine now.